# Съел пол-яблока вкусного / пол яблока вкусного

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис, приставка

Как правильно? Я сомневаюсь потому, что здесь-то *пол-* относится к словосочетанию *яблоко вкусное*.

`Я съел пол-яблока вкусного / пол яблока вкусного.`